# Is there a difference between memory layout of struct _node* next; and struct* next; on 32bit x86 or amd?

Tags: c, struct

I'm learning about memory layout of C struct{}; and wanted to know how is the memory layout for a struct which includes pointer variable to a struct For example:-

```
typedef struct _node{ int data; struct _node* next;} node_t;
```

Comment: Um, the second [isn't legal C](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/TuzDF2).

Comment: `struct*` is a syntax error in all compilers I've tried. What compiler are you using?

Comment: Probably 4 bytes for `data`, then 4 bytes for `next`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The part where OP asked about "*... on 32bit x86 or amd?*".

Answer (score 1):

> …a difference in how memory is laid for a pointer variable to a struct,…

No, there are no differences in how structure pointers are represented in memory. Per C 2018 6.2.5 28:

> All pointers to structure types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as each other.

There are some caveats about that. It does not mean you can freely convert a pointer to a structure of one type and use it as a pointer to a structure of another type. A footnote tells us:

> The same representation and alignment requirements are meant to imply interchangeability as arguments to functions, return values from functions, and members of unions.

Essentially, what this allows you to do is convert pointers to structures back and forth temporarily—as long as, when you use it to reference members of a structure, it has been converted back to its original type. Essentially, any structure pointer can be a temporary holder for any other structure pointer.

There are some additional things you can do with a pointer to a structure. A special rule says a pointer to a structure, suitably converted, points to its first member, and vice-versa (6.7.2.1 15). So, if the first member of a structure is also a structure, that is a situation in which you can convert a pointer to one structure type to a pointer to another structure type and use it to access members. That is a fairly rare occurrence, though.

Largely, I expect the rule about all pointers to structures having the same representation and alignment requirements is to make things work when a structure has been declared (as with `struct foo;`, which makes it known to the compiler) but not yet defined (which tells the compiler what is in it). We want to be able to declare and define pointers to structures when all we know about them so far in the source code is that they exist, not what is in them. If the representation of a pointer to a structure varied depending on what was in it, the compiler would have different notions about what the pointer was after a bare declaration of `struct foo;` than it would have a full definition of the structure.